# Need to Set Up Versioning for a Java EE app

Tags: git, jakarta-ee, unix, cvs

I am asked to set up a version control system for a unix server which hosts a Java EE application.

I have had no experience in setting up a version control for any such systems.

Usually are we suppose to set up the version control like CVS or GIT for the entire contents of the unix server or only the Java EE parts of the application like JSP, Servlets etc.

Usually what files are supposed to be considered while creating the version control.

Which among CVS or GIT whould be a more suitable version control system in my case.

And which one would be a better choice among the two and which one would be simpler to set up as I dont have experience on either of them and the learning curve for learning eihter of them for setting up the same.

Comment: Yes,I mean CVS repository.

Comment: @david.coalis If you are choosing between CVS and Git then choose, ehm, cucumber. I hope you understand the irony. You should know each technology to understand which is the best for **your** development process and environment. I'd personally advise to consider SVN as the most powerful version control system. Git is just a synchronization tool, actually.

Comment: @bahrep: what have you been smoking these days? Git is just a synchronization tool? Learn Git. You're talking nonsense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unusual to store binaries or "the contents of a server" into a VCS. They're typically used to store source files, which can then be used to build and deploy the application.

Every source file of an app is supposed to be in the VCS. And by source file, I also mean resources (like images, script files, CSS files, etc.), config files, build scripts, etc., but not artifacts generated by the build such as jar or war files.

Asking which is the best system between CVS and Git is like asking which is the best between a Ford T and a new Beetle. Nobody uses CVS anymore, because much progress has been done in VCSs since CVS. It's obsolete now. You might consider Mercurial or Subversion, but definitely not CVS.

Comment: I got the first point you made that i need to maintain a repository which can then be used to build and deploy the application so does that mean the other files need not be stored in the repository. And I did not get you in the last point you made "Nobody uses CVS anymore, because much progress has been done in VCSs since CVS. It's obsolete now. You might consider Mercurial or Subversion, but definitely not CVS." What is the Mercurial or the Subversion here mean?

Comment: *Which* other files? Are you alone developing this application? Where do the other developers store their source files? Who asks you to set up a VCS and why? Are you aware that the VCS is a key tool that will have to be used every day by all the developers, and that you and the other developers will have to learn how to use it?

Comment: Mercurial and Subversion are other VCSs. There are much more VCSs than just CVS and Git. Subversion and Mercurial are two other popular VCSs, just like Git. CVS was popular, ten years ago. It's now completely obsolete, because it doesn't offer the functionalities that modern VCSs offer.

Comment: Other files like unix shell scripts,or jar files inside lib directory inside WEB-INF etc. Yes so far I was the only one developing in this application. There might me new additions to the team for which I am asked to do this task.Later after I hopefully install this version control system successfully I will be needed to teach other people as well to use this system.

Comment: Unix shell scripts are source files. External libraries can be stored in the VCS, but you would typically use Maven, Gradle or Ivy to build your app, handle your dependencies and get these libraries from a Maven repository.

Comment: May I ask what would be the learning curve for Subversion or Mercurial when compared to GIT and CVS.

Comment: Definitely forget about CVS. It's shitty compared to alternatives. I don't know for Mercurial, because I don't have any experience with it. Subversion is relatively easy to learn, especialy if you use a graphicall client like TortoiseSVN. The online free book is excellent, and the TortoiseSVN doc also is. Git is more powerful, but also a bit more complex, IMHO. It tends to replace Subversion these days though, so I would start with Git. If you don't know anything about VCSs, it won't be easy in the beginning, especially if you're alone, with nobody to help you. But it's worth learning.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.So I'm willing to go for GIT,Subversion and see which one would be more suitable.So just for convincing the managers who are stuck up on CVS what would be the best way to convince them to go for either GIT,Subversion instead of the CVS repository for my case.

Comment: An SCM is a tool for developers. Managers don't do development, and they shouldn't choose the tools of developers. Show them my answer. Show them that [Google code hosting](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ChoosingAVersionControlSystem) doesn't even care to provide CVS hosting, and that [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/create/) has also abandoned it. All these tools are free. Why choose one that nobody uses anymore because of its vastly inferior quality?